# rxjs process ajax request

Tags: javascript, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to apply the ajax method posted here: https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/master/docs/basics/Epics.md

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax';

// action creators
const fetchUser = username => ({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: username });
const fetchUserFulfilled = payload => ({ type: FETCH_USER_FULFILLED, payload });

// epic
const fetchUserEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(FETCH_USER),
  mergeMap(action =>
    ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${action.payload}`).pipe(
      map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
    )
  )
);

// later...
dispatch(fetchUser('torvalds'));
```

When trying this method, I get the message:

> TypeError: Object(...)(...).pipe is not a function

So pipe doesn't appear to exist. (It concerns the second pipe after the ajax call).
How do I fix this?

I installed the following dependencies:

```
"rxjs": "^6.5.2",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
```

Edit:

I changed my code to `ajax.get` and the calling code:

```
export const fetchTrendingEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_TRENDING_REQUEST),
    mergeMap(async(action) => {
        const res = await fetchPostStats(action.payload);
        console.log(res);
        res.pipe(
          map(response => {
            console.log('response', response);
            setTrendingPlaces({trendingPlaces: response});
          })
        )
    })
);
```

The res was properly printed (showing an observable), but now I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

This is how I create my store in dev:

```
const createEnhancer = (epicMiddleware) => {
  const middleware = [ epicMiddleware, createLogger() ];

  let enhancer;
  if (getEnvironment() === 'development') {
    enhancer = composeWithDevTools(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware),
      // other store enhancers if any
    );

  };

export default (initialState) => {
  const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();
  const enhancer = createEnhancer(epicMiddleware);
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancer);
  epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);
  return store;
}
```

Edit note:

This is code executed in NodeJS (SSR).
I'm struggling with this, don't really understand how this can be so hard to get working without error.
Can't quite see how the example code will ever work when `ajax.getJSON` returns a promise, not an Observable...

Comment: Your mergeMap and the map inside it need to return values; an Observable of actions and an action respectively. Also, what is the fetchPostStats doing? Wondering why you need the async.

Comment: @dez that service performa an rxjs ajax request, and it logs a promise with Observable as return value. Therefore I don’t understand how the pipe can exist (the error that is thrown), and the reason why I made it async. I assume there should be a different explanation for this...

Answer (score 1):

My service that called the ajax request was marked with async because the previous implementation used Axios before the refactoring.
This was the reason why my console logged a promise as return value of the function.
Removing `async` returns the Observable as expected.

As @Dez mentioned in the comments, there is also need to add return values.
And last but not least, rxjs ajax does not work in a NodeJS environment.
Therefore, based on this thread: 
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2099

I have found that someone created the following npm package that I will try out shortly: https://github.com/mcmunder/universal-rxjs-ajax

Answer (score 1):

Axios works fine with rxjs in nodejs, just doing something like this...

```
const { from } = require('rxjs');
const { map } = require('rxjs/operators');
const axios = require('axios');

const responsePromise = axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
const response$ = from(responsePromise);

response$
    .pipe(
        map(response => ({ type: 'RESPONSE_RECEIVED', payload: response.data}))
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I’n sure it does ;-) I wrote my services before I decided on redux-observable and chose for the common approach